# Get all values of a specific column in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, that has say, x number of columns and y number of rows.

I want specifically all the values in the 3rd column.

The obvious way to go about doing this is to put this in a for loop like this

```
for(i=0;i<y-1;i++)
{
   $ThirdColumn[] = $array[$i][3];
}
```

but there is an obvious time complexity of O(n) involved here. Is there a built in way for me to simply extract each of these rows from the array without having to loop in.

For example (this does not work offcourse)

```
$ThirdColumn  = $array[][3]
```

Comment: No, any iteration of this idea, will contain at least one for loop somewhere....its unavoidable

Comment: Post a print_r of your array

Comment: why do you need a print_r of my array ?

Comment: To see how your data is structured

Comment: It would be [2] for the third column, not [3]...

Comment: well, that's correct, but the keys inside our specifically begin from 1. Should have made that clearer in my post

Comment: Alternatively `array_map()` and a callback retrieving the third entry each.

Answer (score 33):

Given a bidimensional array `$channels`:

```
$channels = array(
    array(
        'id' => 100,
        'name' => 'Direct'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 200,
        'name' => 'Dynamic'
    )
);
```

A nice way is using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$_currentChannels = array_map(function ($value) {
    return  $value['name'];
}, $channels);
```

and if you are a potentate (php 5.5+) through [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$_currentChannels = array_column($channels, 'name');
```

Both results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Direct
    [1] => Dynamic
)
```

---

Star guests:
[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (php4+) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (php5.5+)

```
// array array_map ( callable $callback , array $array1 [, array $... ] )
// array array_column ( array $array , mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = null ] )
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a built in way for me to simply extract each of these rows from the array without having to loop in.

Not yet. There *will* be a function soon named [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column). However the complexity will be the same, it's just a bit more optimized because it's implemented in C and inside the PHP engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
   foreach ($array as $val)
   {
       $thirdCol[] = $val[2];
   }
```

Youll endup with an array of all values from 3rd column

Comment: this is off course, what I have stated in my post as the obvious way to go about doing it is by foreach looping, but thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same would be something like `$newArray = array_map( function($a) { return $a['desiredColumn']; }, $oldArray );` though I don't think it will make any significant (if any) improvement on the performance.

Answer (score -2):

You could try this:

```
$array["a"][0]=10;
$array["a"][1]=20;
$array["a"][2]=30;
$array["a"][3]=40;
$array["a"][4]=50;
$array["a"][5]=60;

$array["b"][0]="xx";
$array["b"][1]="yy";
$array["b"][2]="zz";
$array["b"][3]="aa";
$array["b"][4]="vv";
$array["b"][5]="rr";

$output = array_slice($array["b"], 0, count($array["b"]));

print_r($output);
```