# Looping through an object inside of another object

Tags: php

I have an object which contains keys with values that are objects, and inside of those objects there are another objects as value for one of the keys. I have been able to get a specific value from the deep nested object I need by doing 4 loops, but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing so. Here is the object I have:

```
{
  record1: {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: {
      key_x1: value_x1,
      key_x2: value_x2,
      key_x3: value_x3
    }
  }
  record2: {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: {
      key_x1: value_x1,
      key_x2: value_x2,
      key_x3: value_x3
    }
  }
}
```

So, for each record (`record1` and `record2` etc.) I need to pull out the value from `key_x1` and store it in an array. Any ideas on how to accomplish this without having 4 foreach loops?

EDIT: Here is what I have which works, just looks ugly:

```
   $mainObject
   $a = [];
   $dateArray = [];

    foreach ($mainObject as $individualOb) {
        $dates = $individualOb->getDate();
        $a[] = $dates;
    }

    if (empty($a)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        foreach ($a as $date) {
            foreach ($date as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == 'date') {
                    $dateArray[] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach ($dateArray as $value) {
            if(strtotime($value) < strtotime('-1 year') ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show some effort of how you have attempted to solve the problem, where you have gone wrong, and what errors and results you have received.

Comment: is it json string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an object to an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all values of a specific column in a multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159073/get-all-values-of-a-specific-column-in-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: alexi2 Sorry about that, added the code I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could nest the loops like this:

```
foreach ($mainObject as $individualOb) {
    foreach ($individualOb->getDate() as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'date' && strtotime($value) < strtotime('-1 year') ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why you want to return `true` when there are no elements, as `false` seems more logical. Anyway you can do that test straight on `$mainObject`:

```
if (empty($mainObject)) {
    return true;
} else // ...etc.
```

Comment: ignore the returns for now. These loops are actually in a function which I am calling elsewhere. But, in terms of the snippet you posted, I original had tried nesting for each loops and it was writing out double of each wanted value. I think my problem was that I didn't use the key value pairing for the 2nd foreach loop. I will give this code a try and get back at you. :)

Comment: Well, if your code is not about returning false/true, then my answer might not be suitable. But then, please update your question with more relevant code.

Comment: Edit: just tried it and it works like a charm. You are a genius sir :)
Edit 2: the mainObject ALWAYS has one key inside of it, but THAT key can be empty which I think I know how to go about solving now :) Once again, thank you!